# Can verb tense be changed mid-sentence for something that still exists?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, indirect-speech

Look at this sentence:

> I knew that the sky is blue.

To me, it doesn't make sense to say the sky *was* blue since it still is blue. Even so, is it grammatically incorrect to say *I knew that the sky is blue* just because the tenses must be the same?

Answer (score 3):

Saying *I knew that the sky is blue* is correct, assuming the sky is always blue. It is fine to mix the present tense with the past tense when one is expressing a timeless fact. Of course, it is also correct to say *I knew that the sky was blue*, but that only expresses how the sky was blue back then.

Answer (score -1):

> (Yesterday) "I know the sky **is** blue" said 3125.
>
> (Today) 3125 said he knew the sky **was** blue.

Your exact words when you spoke yesterday were; *"... the sky is blue"*. However, the time when you uttered those words was in the past i.e. *yesterday*. You cannot express your thoughts in the past using a present tense. The present tense is also used to speak about facts which are always true e.g; The sun **is** a star in the centre of the solar system. Water **freezes** at 0°C. Tuesday **comes** after Monday. Australia **has** kangaroos etc.

So you should say: "I *know* the sky *is* blue" if it is a fact and you know the sky is always blue. If instead you say,

> I **knew** the sky is blue

you are in fact stating that yesterday you knew without a doubt the sky is blue. Since then however, your certainty has changed and effectively speaking, you don't know if it is true any more (yesterday you knew the sky is blue but today you don't know). The sentence is grammatically correct but it struggles to make logical sense.

Comment: I don't think that the certainty has to have changed. If, for example, you recall something and want to make a point of the fact that at that time you already knew that the sky is blue (and might still know that), this works perfectly fine. "I was only four years old at that time. He was trying to make me believe the sky is originally red, but I knew the sky is blue." Or, you could use it as an idiom for somebody trying to make you believe something, but common sense tells you it is wrong. So the blue sky is just something, everybody knows.

Comment: I disagree. When referring to the past and specifically retelling an anecdote, a story or an episode you need to use the past tense. In your example it would be far more natural to say: I was only four years old at that time. He was trying to make me believe the sky **was** originally red, but I knew the sky **was** blue. This structure is called *reported speech* or [*indirect speech*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech).

Comment: You are only reporting the words said by another person, if it is direct speech, then it would be legitimate to write: I was only four years old at that time. He was trying to make me believe the sky was originally red, but I replied indignantly, **"I know the sky is blue!"**

Comment: You're right, I should have written " He was trying to make me believe the sky was originally red". But I still think "I knew the sky is blue" can be correct after that. I knew it then, it still is blue now.

Comment: @skymninge I beg to differ. *I knew the sky was blue* means at a specific point in the past you held this belief, it does not necessarily follow you have since changed your idea. Let us pick another example, "When I was 10 I loved reading books." Does this exclude the possibility of my enjoying books later in life? No, why should it? If however, I say: "When I was 10 I *used to love* reading books" it would be correct to presume today I no longer read or enjoy books. Likewise: *I knew the sky **used to be** blue* OR *I **used to know** the sky was blue* means today it is no longer true.

Comment: "I knew that the sky is blew" very simply means, yesterday (for some reason the issue arose, and) I knew that the sky is blue.  "Yesterday my father asked me what color the Horsehead Nebula is. I knew that the Horsehead Nebula is green. So I answered 'Yes I do.'"  "It's that simple."  "the sky is blue" is a GENERAL COMMENT on "the sky".  Much as "the McDonald's log is red".  (Omitting the 'that' changes nothing in this.)

Comment: @JoeBlow You realize that this question is two years old, but anyway, I hope you have read my all answer and not just dwelt on the last citation. Because I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: I love old questions!